# No Info.plist found for target application at path build/Debug-iphonesimulator/XXX.app/Info.plist

Tags: ios, swift, coded-ui-tests, xcode-ui-testing, xcode8

No Info.plist found for target application at path build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxx[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MQ4O.png).app/Info.plist

i can't test UItest file and same file run on other machine..what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ->
Uninstall the application from simulator and run again.

And restart Xcode and simulator.

Comment: nothing happen i restart both xcode and simulator ..still after test same error.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have built the product for testing by the following way: *Product > Build For > Testing*